# How to print result depends on condition ?

Tags: java, oop

1. My Code :

   ```
       public class Triangle 
      {
         private PointClass v1 = new PointClass();
         private PointClass v2 = new PointClass();
         private PointClass v3 = new PointClass();



         public Triangle (PointClass v1 , PointClass v2 , PointClass v3)

       {
            this.v1 = v1;
            this.v2 = v2;
            this.v3 = v3;
       }

       public void printtype()
    {

          if (v1 != v2 && v2 !=v3 && v1 !=v3)

        {

          System.out.println(" The Triangle is scalene"); 

        }

          if (v1 != v2 || v3 !=v2 )
       {

          System.out.println(" The Triangle is isosceles"); 

       }


         if (v1 == v2 && v2== v3 && v1 == v3)

      {
          System.out.println(" The Triangle is equilateral");
      }


    }


   }
   ```
2. Main Method :

   ```
     public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      PointClass v1 = new PointClass(1, 2);
      PointClass v2 = new PointClass(1, 2);
      PointClass v3 = new PointClass(1, 2);
      Triangle tr = new Triangle(v1, v2, v3);
      tr.printtype();
   }
   ```
3. The output is :

   The Triangle is scalene

   The Triangle is isosceles

I want to print results of conditions depends on the inputs of PointClass such as V1 , V2 and V3 and be one result not two of them

How can i do this ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Are `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` *really* the lengths of the sides?

Comment: Also, you should be comparing `PointClass` instances using `equals`, not `==`.

Comment: First of all, don't use == to compare two objects you should override equals to check equality. And then just sort your conditions (3th then 1st then 2nd) and use `else if`instead of `if`.

Comment: -1, put more more effort into the code you post by providing a consistent formatting and preferably following Java conventions.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you're looking for `else if`:

```
if (condition1) {
  System.out.println("1");
} else if (condition2) {
  System.out.println("2");
} else {
  System.out.println("other");
}
```

Only one of these `System.out.println` statements will be executed: if `condition1` and `condition2` are both true, only `1` is printed, because `condition1` is matched first.

Comment: i have tried else if but it got the same result @Andy_Turner

Comment: Since the code you've shown wouldn't give the output you've shown, you are clearly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

== compares object references, it checks to see if the two point to the same object (which they are not). Which is why you are having the 2 outputs.

You should use `.equals`

```
if (!v1.equals(v2) && !v2.equals(v3) && !v1.equals(v3))
{
 ...
}
else if(...)
{
...
}

// use this custom equals for your case
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof PointClass)) {
        return false;
    }

    PointClass temp = (PointClass) obj;

    return this.x.equals(obj.x)
        && this.y.equals(obj.y);
}
```

Comment: How i use it ?? @deviantxdes

Comment: @MadJlzz nope i read alot but the practicing is different than reading

Comment: @deviantxdes public int x = 0;
 public int y = 0;
 
 public  PointClass()
 {
  
 }
 
 public PointClass(int x , int y)
 {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
 }

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAli, don't show code in comments. Show it in your post. And while you're at it format the entire post correctly.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAli you don't understand anything you read then. This is basic things to know if you wan't to progress otherwise you won't be able to progress.

Comment: @MadJlzz nope i have read alot you don't know anything about me i know all of basics if i don't am not be coding with oop ! so if 're a perfect at coding why you don't answer my question ?? .. you also not knowing the answer of my question ,,

Comment: @deviantxdes got the same result i have made another way now it works for me it's so long by code but it's okay  :) ...  Big Thank for you :)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAli I've answered to you with details if you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Look, I am not trying to put your down. I am simply observing and giving you some advice.

Like the others said, when you're using `==` on `Objects`, it compares references.

A reference is a block created in the `Stack` containing a memory address. When you're calling the `new` operator, Java is actually reserving a new address memory in the `Stack` for you.

This reference points to the actual `Object` in the `Heap` where you'll find everything your object is made of.

So when you're doing something like :
`v1 == v2`, you're actually looking if the memory adress of `Object` v1 is actually the same adress as `Object` v2 which isn't because you've called `new` operator twice.

Here is a drawing of what I mean :[image: Java Stack && Heap]

You can prove it by using :

```
System.out.println("V1 object : " + v1);
System.out.println("V2 object : " + v2);
```

And you'll see that the addresses are different.

Finally if you wan't to compare objects, this is possible but you need to tell Java how to compare them. This is done by `@Override` the `equals(Object obj)` method defined in the `Object` class.

In your example it could look like this (you need to override this method in PointClass) :

```
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Pointclass p) {
    if (this.x == p.x && this.y == p.y)
      return true;
    return false;
 }
```

Now if you use `v1.equals(v2)`, this gonna check if the points are located in the same position.

Hope it's clearer now about Java objects instantiation and references.

Comment: @MadJIzz thank you mate :) i have done another method yesterday but thank you for ur job it's nice (y)